# Why the default sample rate is 48000 in Web Audio Context rather that no one could even hear?

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

The default sample rate of web audio context is 48000. However, most people can only hear 20-20000Hz and almost no one can hear over 30000Hz, why it is set to 48000?

```js
var a = new AudioContext();
var samplerate = a.sampleRate;
alert(samplerate); // 48000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that 20kHz is approximately the highest frequency humans can hear is exactly the reason why values above 40kHz are so commonly used by audio hardware.

To represent a signal digitally you have to sample it with at least twice the frequency. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

By default an `AudioContext` uses the `sampleRate` of the audio hardware which is commonly 44.1kHz (thanks to the CD format) or 48kHz these days.